# iOS Swift Adding Object To Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to add the retrieved object from Parse to an array. It has found the user, it is printed in my logs. All the key names match up, I can't seem to find why both my userArray and imageFiles array are printed to the logs as empty. Thanks for the help!

```
    var userArray: [String] = []

var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

var imageFiles = [PFFile]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geopoint: PFGeoPoint!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            println(geopoint)

            var user = PFUser.currentUser()

            user["location"] = geopoint
            user.save()

            var query = PFUser.query()
            query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:geopoint)
            query.limit = 10
           query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                for user in users {

                 self.userArray.append(user["name"] as! String)

                 self.imageFiles.append(user["profilePicFile"] as! PFFile)

                    println(user)
                }



      })

  }
}


    self.refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    self.refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(self.refresher)
    //follow udemy to get pull to refresh , need update users
    println(userArray)
    println(imageFiles.count)


}


func updateUsers() {

    self.userArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.imageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    var aquery = PFUser.query()
    aquery.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
    var cools = aquery.findObjects()

    var query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: cools[0]["location"] as! PFGeoPoint!)
    query.limit = 10
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        for user in users {

            self.userArray.append(user["name"] as! String)

            self.imageFiles.append(user["profilePicFile"] as! PFFile)

        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()


        self.refresher.endRefreshing()

    })

}
```

Comment: Print them inside the for user in users {} loop, it will print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because `PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` is an asynchronous method that takes a callback closure as a parameter to fire off as soon as the asynchronous work is done. So `viewDidLoad` will call that method but continue on and print `userArray` before the `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` callback gets fired.

This is a big feature of functional programming languages so I suggest reading up on closures when you can.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-from-scratch-closures--cms-23138
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

If you put the `println` statements after you iterate the users inside of the callback, you will see your data:

```
for user in users {
    self.userArray.append(user["name"] as! String)
    self.imageFiles.append(user["profilePicFile"] as! PFFile)
        println(user)
    }
}
println(userArray) // you will see userArray is populated
println(imageFiles.count)
```